# Method chaining in php

Tags: php

I have the following class

```
class FormValidator{

    public function __construct() {}

    public function __destruct(){}

    private $value;

    public function Value($value){
        $this->value = trim($value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function Required(){
        if(empty($this->value)){
           return false;
        }
        else{
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function MinLength($length){
        $len = strlen($this->value);
        if($len < $length){
           return false;
        }
        else{
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

In my php code, I'm calling -

```
 $validator = new FormValidator();
 $result = $validator->Value("")->Required()->MinLength(5)->SomeOtherMethod();
```

The above line gives the error `Call to a member function MinLength() on a non-object ...`

UPDATE: I require to stop to call MinLength() if Required() returns false.

How can I make my statement functioning?

Comment: `Required` return either a boolean or $this. Perhaps you could first check for Required and MinLength `if($validator->Required() && $validator->MinLength(5)) {
    $validator->Value("")->SomeOtherMethod();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of [exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) instead, which would handle errors while the methods themselves would always return the current instance.

This becomes:

```
<?php
class FormValidationException extends \Exception 
{
}

class FormValidator
{
  private $value;

  public function Value($value): self
  {
    $this->value = trim($value);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @return $this
   * @throws FormValidationException
   */
  public function Required(): self
  {
    if (empty($this->value)) {
      throw new \FormValidationException('Value is required.');
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $length
   * @return $this
   * @throws FormValidationException
   */
  public function MinLength(int $length): self
  {
    $len = strlen($this->value);
    if ($len < $length) {
      throw new \FormValidationException("Value should be at least {$length} characters long.");
    }
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$validator = new FormValidator();
try {
  $result = $validator->Value("lodddl")->Required()->MinLength(5);
} catch (\FormValidationException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/OFcPV**

**Edit**: since OP is using PHP 5.2 (sadly), here's a version for it, removing `\`s before root namespace, return type declarations and argument types.

**Demo for PHP 5.2: https://3v4l.org/cagWS**

Comment: Oh you a little faster. This is how it's done. Method be like an interface and return always the same type.

Comment: Looks good. Does php v5.2 support this? The reference does not have any version mentioned.

Comment: @DanielW.with that logic, the same type returned from any method is the instance.  Which means you are reliant upon exceptions for anything otherwise.  This highlights why fluent interfaces are confusing and painful.

Comment: @s.k.paul Here's a [PHP 5.2 compatible version](https://3v4l.org/cagWS), but you should definitely upgrade whenever you have the opportunity.

Comment: My client is sticked to v5.2.

Comment: @Progrock Agreed that fluent interfaces are generally to be avoided. I thought this was a bit off-topic to mention in the answer (more a subject for the code design stackexchange), but you're absolutely right.

Comment: If you put all the methods values into variables and append a function to check the results later it's less "confusing": `$validator->setRequired(true)->setMinLength(123)->validate();` - all setters can easily return `$this` without any logic at all (no exceptions). It also allows easier unit testing.

Comment: what is the problem of my answer ? I answered this question with the fast way and what he said. am i right?

Comment: @ttrasn keep discussions of your answer within your answer's comments.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of working with Exceptions (the solution of @Jeto), you can also work with an array holding all errors.
A benefit of this solution is that you'll get multiple errors in one run, instead of breaking at the first error.

```
<?php
class FormValidator
{
  private $value;

  private $_errors = array();

  public function Value($value)
  {
    $this->value = trim($value);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @return $this
   */
  public function Required()
  {
    if (empty($this->value)) {
      $this->_errors[] = 'Value is required';
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $length
   * @return $this
   */
  public function MinLength($length)
  {
    $len = strlen($this->value);
    if ($len < $length) {
      $this->_errors[] = "Value should be at least {$length} characters long.";
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function hasErrors(){
    return (count($this->_errors) > 0);
  }

  public function getErrors(){
      return $this->_errors;
  }
}

$validator = new FormValidator();
$validator->Value("1234")->Required()->MinLength(5);
if($validator->hasErrors()){
    echo implode('<br>',$validator->getErrors());
}
```

[Example here](https://3v4l.org/uUITV)

Comment: @Progrock thanks, that's the copy past monster when writing quick responses :)

Answer (score 1):

cause method **Required()** returns `false` not `Class object`:

```
    if(empty($this->value)){
        return false;
    }
```

You must change your code to.

```
$result = $validator->Value("");
if($result->Required()){ // if is not false do 
   $result->MinLength(5)->SomeOtherMethod();
}else{
    // do anything if value is empty.
}
```

Comment: Now there is inconsistency between method returns.  What's chainable, what is not?  The class' interface is no longer obvious.

Comment: @Progrock of course, I understood my answer not complete and thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In the following methods you are calling to a method on a boolean value.

```
Required();

MinLength();
```

In order to solve this problem in the MinLength method:

```
if($len < $length){

    // As a flag
    $this->failed = true;

    return $this;
}
```

and the SomeOtherMethod():

```
public function SomeOtherMethod() {
    if (! $this->failed) {
        // do something...
    } else {
        // do nothing...
    }
}
```

> Do the same for the `Requied()` method